# css border makes space to content

Tags: css, border

When I add a border to a div, the content inside doesn't have 100% `width` and `height` anymore.

I already added `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;` as well as `box-sizing: border-box;` but the background still shows up at some zoom levels.

Is this a browser bug? On Firefox the red background never shows up (but Firefox has different zoom levels, too).

[red background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE6nv.png)

```css
 #outside {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: red;
        border: 1px solid #808080;
        border-radius: 12px;
        height: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #content {
        background: green;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="outside">
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is not any bug. border affects the inner width of the element.

Comment: @sajjadrezaei Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What do you want to fix? Do you mean the white space between the green background and the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

In browers there is some inner css
You can write in your css file

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

this style will be appliced for all document, not only for div id="outside".
I use also this file to apply the default code : [Normalise.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)